# Changing an object inside a method

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort, singly-linked-list

I am using a merge sort algorithm to sort a linked list

```
void node::merge_sort()
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    node *p = new node;
    node *q = new node;
    this->divide(&p, &q);
    p->merge_sort();
    q->merge_sort();
    this=merge_lists(p, q);
}
```

but I have to change the object inside this method due to which I typed `this=merge_lists(p,q)`. But this is giving an error saying nolvalue. Is there any alternative way?

The divide function is used to divide the list into two parts and store them in p and q.

Comment: Are the pointers here really necessary? Even if they are, the `new` isn't.

Comment: Assigning `this` won't work! Design your `merge_sort()` function as static class member or outside the `node` class.

Comment: @chris Yes they are needed to store the address of the two halves and change them in divide function

Comment: You are really messing up concepts here. What is the `head` of a `node`? The `head` **is a** `node`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot reassign `this`.  The analogy would be if I walked up to you and said "You're now that body over there".  Your response would be "that doesn't even make sense".  And you'd be right.  What you want to do is *change the state of the current object*, not replacing it entirely.

Also, there's no reason for allocating dynamic objects here.  Don't do that.  That makes your code slower and more prone to error.  In fact, your interface doesn't appear to need pointers at all

```
void node::merge_sort()
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    node left, right;
    divide(left, right);
    left.merge_sort();
    right.merge_sort();
    *this = merge_lists(left, right); //this line is the key to answering to your question
}
```

And then change your function signatures from:

```
void node::divide(node** left, node** right);
node merge_lists(node* left, node* right);
node& node::operator=(const node& right_hand_side);
```

to

```
void node::divide(node& left, node& right);
node merge_lists(node& left, node* right);
node& node::operator=(const node& right_hand_side);
node& node::operator=(node&& right_hand_side); //along with this line
```

The keys here are `*this =`, which reassigns the value held by the current object, rather than attempting to replace the current object's existence.  Also, a move assignment operator to make it fast.